How to set large numbers of programmatically generated color variations in lightning-datatable cells?
I want to set the background color to a programatically generated color rather than picking from pre-defined classes. Is that possible?
(This is a solution for using pre-defined classes How to dynamically color a cell on a lightning-datatable on a LWC? that I want to avoid.)

Do you have checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/420329/how-to-dynamically-color-a-cell-on-a-lightning-datatable-on-a-lwc

Hi @TusharJadav I had checked that. I've edited the question because that does not meet my needs as it uses pre-defined classes.

Yes.
When building the data rows, generate a CSS style in each row; using hsl seems the simplest way to generate the color:
        let color = 1;
        for (const item of this.items) {
            // Make the consecutive colors distinctly different
            const hue = (color * 223) % 360;
            row['_STYLE_'] = `background-color: hsl(${hue}deg 50% 95%);`;
            ...   
            this.data.push(row);
            color++;
        }

and reference that via the cellAttributes in the column definitions:
        this.columns.push({
            label: columnLabel,
            fieldName: columnKey,
            ...
            cellAttributes: {
                style: { fieldName: '_STYLE_' },
            }
        });

to be set as the cell style rather than setting the cell class that is more commonly described.

This is cool - I wonder how radically this can be used to modify the layout of the cells, beyond colours... :-)

@FelixvanHove Yep, as style takes priority over class.
